# How to initialize a numpy array with lists

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a np.array filled with lists. The array I want to create is a 2D one. I wonder if there is a way to create this array full of lists kind of like `np.zeros((10, 10))` but lists instead of zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wish to use a list of lists:

```
import numpy as np
l = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
np.array(l)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [2, 3, 4],
#        [3, 4, 5]])
```

if you have multiple list of same dimension:

```
import numpy as np
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [2,3,4]
l3 = [3,4,5]
np.array([l1, l2, l3])
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [2, 3, 4],
#        [3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: thanks I tried your way but like array = np.array([[[0, 0, 0] for k in range(10)] for j in range(10)]]) an it works

Comment: @Alex I see, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method `np.array()`

Where you can fill each list with numbers, just make sure that each list(list 1, list 2 ... ) all contain the same number of elements.

```
arr = np.array([[list 1],
                [list 2],
                [list 3],
                 ...
                [list n]])
```

Comment: Note that this method will create an array of shape `(n,1,n)` and not `(n,n)` because you wrap each list in a new list which it's interpreted as another dimension

Comment: i meant [list 1] can be [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate a random array of lists then you can use **np.random.random**

```
>>np.random.random((5,5))
array([[0.72158455, 0.09803052, 0.1160546 , 0.55904644, 0.79821847],
       [0.36929337, 0.15455486, 0.25862476, 0.44324732, 0.06120428],
       [0.95063129, 0.38533428, 0.96552669, 0.07803165, 0.46604093],
       [0.04999251, 0.8845952 , 0.8090841 , 0.64154241, 0.95548603],
       [0.83991298, 0.85053047, 0.36522791, 0.89616194, 0.10960277]])
```

or to generate random values between a range you can use **np.random.uniform**

```
>>np.random.uniform(low=0,high=10,size=(5,5))
array([[4.9572961 , 5.44408409, 6.74143596, 6.57745607, 5.90485241],
       [7.37032096, 0.70533052, 2.93912528, 8.54091449, 7.6188883 ],
       [8.27882354, 0.02749772, 6.45388547, 4.94197824, 9.29715119],
       [6.72579011, 4.65019332, 4.67693981, 2.52006744, 8.3876697 ],
       [8.99122563, 3.70552959, 2.50082311, 8.68846022, 6.34887673]])
```